# How to implement a complex token-matching algorithm in SOLR

Tags: solr, token, fuzzy-search, relevance

**Problem Description**

I'm trying to implement a custom algorithm to match user provided **free-text** input, a company name such as "Ford Motor", against a reference data source consisting of 1.4 million company names.

The algorithm executes following steps:

**Step 1)** Performs an "Exact Match", followed by "Begins Match" and finally "Contains Match" of user provided search input. Results from this step are also sorted in the same order.

**Step 2)** Performs a token by token match of search input with reference company name.

Every token is matched in following order: Exact, Begins, Contains, Levenshtein Distance (< 0.2) and Refined Soundex.

E.g. If user input is "Foord Motur Holding" and it's being matched against "The Ford Motor Holdings Company" then first token "Foord" will match "Ford" based on Soundex match, second token "Motur" will  match "Motor" based on Edit Distance Algo and and last token "Holding" will match "Holdings" via Begins match.

**Scoring:**
Every token match is first scored on a scale that rates the matching technique, with Exact match being the best and Soundex being the worst.

The overall score is calculated, on a scale of 0-100%, by calculating a weighted average of individual token-match scores. Weights are assigned based on index-order of token i.e. the first token has highest weight and last token has lowest.

**My Partial Solution**

I have implemented a simple schema in solr to store referance company names. A String field (called companyName), a simple text field (called as companyText) copied from string and another text field (called as companySoundex) copied from string and using PhoneticFilterFactory for Refined Soundex based matching.

I have been able to replicate step 1) in a single solr query.

For step 2) I plan to fire 3 parallel queries to solr server. First query performing a simple text search on companyText field, second query performing fuzzy match using ~ operator on companyText field and third query performing soundex match on companySoundex field. I plan to somehow combine the results from these 3 parallel queries to get desired final result.

**Questions:**

1) Is there a better way to replicate Step 2) of original algorithm?

2) Even if I go with my "three-parallel-queries" approach then how to get the "right" sorting order as I get in the original algorithm ? 
I guess the main problem is how to compare the solr scores from these 3 entirely different queries to do the final combining of results

Thanks for reading this long question. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the DisMax query parser. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxRequestHandler

For each separate query, you'll actually build up separate fields in the index for matching. Then use DisMax to combine the queries in a weighted fashion.

I suggest giving up on your 3 parallel queries approach now. Last time I looked into this it was impossible to relate scores from 2 separate queries. It just doesn't work. If you want a single set of results sorted by score, you have to figure out how to do this in a single query.

Comment: I'm using the edismax parser for my 1st query that does full string match (see Step 1) as follows:  q=(* FORD\ MOTOR * )&qf=companyName&defType=edismax&bq=(companyName:FORD\ MOTOR*)^20bf=fieldLength(companyName). Boost query pushes the Exact and Begins matches above those based on Contains. This part of query takes maximum time as I found by comparing query time with and without boost. So I feel that the performance may not be acceptable if I combine 3 queries together and try boosting using multiple bq and bf values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, This functionality can not be achieved in out of the box handlers that Solr provides. You should be better with writing a custom query handler that handles and scores the results in this manner.